# I want to refresh form submit page but do not resubmit it again in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, forms

**AFTER CLICK SUBMIT BUTTON IT REDIRECTED INDEX PAGE, I WANT TO REFRESH(using browser refresh button) INDEX PAGE BUT NOT RESUBMIT THAT FORM**

```
  <form action="{{ route('categories.store') }}" method="POST" role="form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <label for=" name">Category Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
            <input class="form-control input_text" id="name" required placeholder="Category Name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
            <label for=" slug">Category Slug</label><span class="required">*</span>
            <input class="form-control slug_text" id="slug" required placeholder="Category Slug" type="text" name="slug" value="{{ old('slug') }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <a href="{{ route('categories.index') }}" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by resubmit? Redirect?

Comment: when i refresh output page after submit form, it insert data once again or update data again!

Comment: @akakib: Please display your controller code

Comment: Welcome. In your controller action, after successful validation and insertion, redirect to `route('categories.create')`

Comment: can you share the method part of this form?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the redirect or back helpers.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#available-methods

In your CategoriesController:

```
public function handleFormSubmit (Request $req) {
    // form validations...
    // DB operations...
    return redirect()->route('name.of.route.with.form');
}
```

OR

```
public function handleFormSubmit (Request $req) {
    // form validations...
    // DB operations...
    return back();
}
```

OR

```
public function handleFormSubmit (Request $req) {
    // form validations...
    // DB operations...
    return redirect()->back();
}
```